# What's the purpose of having "env [shell]" as an interpreter?

Tags: shell-script, shell, environment-variables, interpreter

I already stumbled over `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on numerous occasions and never questioned it. Now, I'm wondering what the purpose of wrapping the shell interpreter in an `env` command, i.e. why not just write `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/sh` or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

I think this became popular because of python.

With this you can do

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

for example and be quite sure `env` will find the right version and location for the executable.

Then this migrated to other shells because it seems like a good practice to always do even if you know where that particular shell is.